# Using querySelector() in Vue Compostion API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm new to Vue Composition API and need to use `document.querySelector`. However, it is not working as expected. If I write

```
<nav class="home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed">

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);
const target = document.querySelector(".home-menu");
observer.observe(target);
console.log(target);
```

`target` is `null`. Reading the docs, I see the `ref` attribute, and if I

```
<nav ref="navbar" class="home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed">
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const target = ref("navbar");
console.log(target);
```

an object is logged.

Is `ref` the way that you get a DOM element in Composition API?
Can I now use `target` in my observer object?
Is it equivalent to `querySelector`?

I tried

```
import { ref } from "vue";
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

const target = ref("navbar");
observer.observe(target);
```

but got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: IntersectionObserver.observe: Argument 1 does not implement interface Element.

Comment: Vue template refs are _not_ like `querySelector`. `querySelector` takes a CSS selector and returns the matching element, if it exists. With template refs, you define a ref and use it in the template.
Think of it like this, instead: you define a `ref`, as usual, and then, when the template is evaluated, the element with `ref="name"` _uses_ the ref you defined, a bit like variable access.

Comment: With `querySelector`, the DOM comes first, and you select something from it.
With a template ref, the ref comes first, and then a element binds itself to that ref.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ref` approach, calling the variable with the same name you declared the ref in the template:

```js
const navbar = ref(null);
```

However, you should await the component to be mounted to observe:

```js
onMounted(() => {
  observer.observe(target);
})
```

remember also to disconnect it when you unmount the component:

```js
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  observer.disconnect();
})
```

Comment: Thanks guys for quick concise answers. I never ran into this trouble with vue 2. I guess running querySelector() from methods option does same thing.

Comment: And for useful utilities for things like this, [VueUse](https://vueuse.org) is incredible.

Answer (score 15):

The reason `document.querySelector` is returning `null` is that the DOM does not contain that element yet.
The `script setup` runs when the component is *created*, so the component's DOM has not been created yet.

You can use the `onMounted` lifecycle hook to run code when the component has been mounted. I created [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) to demonstrate this.

From [the Lifecycle docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html):

> For example, the `onMounted` hook can be used to run code after the component has finished the initial rendering and created the DOM nodes

**There are then two approaches to achieve what you want.** You can use continue to use `querySelector`, or you can use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html).
Personally, I use template refs for static elements (such as navbars, etc.) and `querySelector` for dynamic selections.

### Using Template Refs

A template ref is a regular Vue ref, but by connecting it to an element or child component via the `ref` attribute you can obtain a direct reference to that element or component.
If you connected it to an element, the value will be that element; if you connected it to a child component, the value will be that component's component instance; if nothing is connected to it, the value will be `null`.

#### Steps

- Create a ref:

  ```js
  const navbar = ref(null);
  ```

  This will be used to refer to the element.
- Connect the template ref to the element by setting the `ref` attribute on the element to the name you used for the template ref:

  ```html
  <nav ref="navbar" ...>
  ```

  Paraphrasing the Template Refs docs:
  `ref` is a special attribute. It allows us to obtain a direct reference to a specific DOM element or child component instance after it's mounted.
- Connect the observer when the component is mounted:

  ```js
  onMounted(() => {
    observer.observe(navbar.value);
  })
  ```

  Paraphrasing the docs again:
  Note that you can only access the ref **after the component is mounted**. If you try to access `navbar` before then, it will be `null`. This is because the element doesn't exist until after the first render!
- Optionally (see below), disconnect the observer when the component is being unmounted:

  ```js
  onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    observer.disconnect();
  })
  ```

  Note that I don't believe this is technically necessary, as the observer should be garbage collected when the component is destroyed.
  You can fiddle around with [this experiment I did in the SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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), trying to create a memory leak.

#### Code Example

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";

const el = ref(null);

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  console.log(entries)
});

onMounted(() => {
  observer.observe(el.value)
})

// Probably optional
onUnmounted(() => {
  observer.disconnect()
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="el">
    I'm the target!
  </div>
</template>
```

### Using `querySelector`

Alternatively, you can still use `querySelector`. The same lifecycle considerations apply.

```html
<nav class="home-menu ...">
```

```js
onMounted(() => {
  const target = document.querySelector(".home-menu");
  observer.observe(target);
})
```

#### Code Example

```html
<script setup>
import { onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  console.log(entries)
});

onMounted(() => {
  const target = document.querySelector(".target");
  observer.observe(target);
})

// Probably optional
onUnmounted(() => {
  observer.disconnect()
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="target">
    I'm the target!
  </div>
</template>
```

### Other Docs

This is the diagram from the Lifecycle docs:

[image: Vue Lifecycle Diagram]

### Side Notes

The reason `console.log(target)` did log an object is because a Vue ref *is* an object. The actual value is accessed via the `value` property.
The technical reason for this is that Vue can then detect when that property is accessed, and do its reactivity magic; including when it was a complete reassignment of the value.